# Xcode Doesn't include signing cert "X" when downloading it

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

One of our provisioning profiles has some weird behaviour, where it doesn't work, when downloading it.

For development (debug) it just works with the `Apple Development` cert and the `match Development` profile, but for the AppStore (release) config it does not with `Apple Distribution` and `match AppStore`.

All of our certificates and provisioning profiles are up-to-date and not invalid nor expired.
The weird part here is, when trying to choose (download) the profile inside Xcode, I get this error:
[image: download profile]

But weirdly when I try to import it, by downloading it from the Apple Developer portal as a `.mobileprovision` file and moving it into xcode, it doesn't:
[image: imported profile]

I already tried creating a new profile, but this doesn't solve the problem.

The biggest problem is on our CI, because we don't know how to fix this, because we are not able to just import it that way. We are using Fastlane and see the problem with the [build_app action](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/build_app/#build_app).

What could be the problem here?